# Further edits are not allowed until tomorrow?

Tags: discussion, support

Today, when I tried to edit my own question I got the below error.

> Too many edits

> You have already edited 17 of your own posts today (not including very recent posts). Further edits are not allowed until tomorrow.
>
> Please contact a moderator if you require assistance.

I haven't edited my own posts today but it's showing that I have edited 17 of my own post. How is it possible?

Comment: it just thinks your a bot because of recent flurry of activity, i'm guessing. when i checked the mod queue and saw there were 20+ edits, my first thought wondered what was going on too! all good, certainly appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @albert Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've [created a lot of tag wikis and excerpts yesterday](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/users/23272/pluviophile?tab=activity&sort=revisions). Those apparently count against this rather rare rate limit, even though the limit is not applied when you edit the tag wikis and excerpts themselves.

This rate limit is probably trying to prevent users from mass-vandalizing or mass-bumping their old posts; see [Getting "Too many edits [...] Further edits are not allowed until tomorrow"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91097/295232) for more details. I'm not sure if it was an intentional decision to count tag wikis and excerpts as well for this limit; you might have written the first revision but otherwise they feel more like community-owned posts.

Answer (score 2):

there was a mod-queue entry for too many edits to this question: [Where Can I find the Developers Survey Dataset?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/17817/where-can-i-find-the-developers-survey-dataset) it was flagged under "possible vandalism". Not sure if it helps, but I unflagged it

Comment: Thanks It helps.